# When was the default AccountController sample changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I asked this question over on the asp.net forums, and nobody seems to know what i'm talking about.  I'm not sure why that is, but I figured I'll ask here to see if there is anyone with some insight.

Back when MVC2 was released, it included a sample AccountController that wrapped the built-in Membership and FormsAuthentication classes with testable interfaces and services.  I read a lot about this, and it was considered a good thing because the Membership and FormsAuthentication classes were not easily testable.

Recently, I generated a new sample project with my up to date (SP1, MVC3, Tools Update, etc..) environment and I find that the AccountController is now much simpler.  Gone are the Interfaces and MembershipService and FormsAuthenticationServices.  The sample now calls the Membership and FormsAuthentication classes directly.

I'm wondering if anyone knows when this happened and why?  Are the testable interfaces no longer considered correct?  Was there a technical reason to change this?

The best I can figure is that this happened as a part of the change to remove a possible vulnerability when passing return url's on the open url.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Account Controller was changed with the MVC3 tools update (When they also included the use of jQuery via Nuget)

Comment: Thanks @Skud, That helps.  I do admit, the ability to update jQuery via nuget is fantastic.  Do you have any idea why the change was made?

Comment: Not a clue, bar the fix they placed in there to stop non-local redirects. The asp.net MVC overview pages says "AccountController Improvements : The AccountController in the Internet project template has been greatly improved" ... So who knows what the 'exact' reason for doing it was.

Answer (score 3):

The new model resembles EF's code first approach where the `AccountModel` is a POCO class. Inside the new API there are no longer abstractions but direct calls to static methods such as `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` making this code difficult to unit test. Not something I would recommend basing your real world application code upon.

And, yes, they have fixed a vulnerability inside the `LogOn` method which was not verifying if the return url is a relative url before redirecting.

Personally I would recommend you using abstractions in order to weaken the coupling between your controller logic and its dependencies. This will make the code easier to unit test.

For me passing all those domain models to views without using view models are total anti-patterns and I have never bothered with them. I simply create an empty project and do the things my way. I mean in the default project they even use `ViewBag` for Christ sake!

Comment: So the AccountController sample was changed by EF 4.1?  That seems rather odd.  I'm also confused why they would change it to match EF when Membership does not use EF, and we're discouraged from adding the Membership tables to our models...

Comment: @Mystere Man, no it doesn't use EF. It simply matches the same model where the AccoutModel is a POCO class. The code is equivalent as they both end up calling the `SqlMembershipProvider`, it's just that the new model calls directly `Membership.ValidateUser` whereas in ASP.NET MVC 2 they were using an abstraction.

Comment: Right, but I guess my question is Why?  Why backtrack on the testable models?  I was hoping someone was privy to the design decisions, since there was a lot of talk about the testable models when they were introduced, but then they were changed without so much as a peep.

Comment: @Mystere Man, honestly I don't know why the ASP.NET MVC team decided to change the AccountController by making it more difficult to unit test and more coupled to ASP.NET infrastructure classes such as `FormsAuthentication`. Maybe in order to make the code shorter. Actually the people that apply TDD don't bother with the default ASP.NET MVC project. They simply do, well, TDD. For all the others (which for me are the majority) they decided to provide some easier to understand template and have some application running without much *hassle*. Well, the *hassles* come later as SO questions :-)